# ReactJS render elements with js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

Suppose I have:

```
class myComponent extends Component {

myFunction() {
//I would like to loop through two iterables, and make as many rows and columns
    let r;
    for (let i= 0; i <= SMTH1; i++) {
//add a <tr> opening tag
      for (let j= 0; j <= SMTH2; j++) {
        // add a <td> opening and </td> closing
        }
//add a </td> closing tag
    }

      return r;
}

render() {
    return <div>
      <table>
        {this.myFunction()}
        </table>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

How would I make it so that in the end I would have SMTH1 amount of rows, each containing SMTH2 amount of columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to decide how many rows and columns you want to create. You can do it using `Array(ROW_COUNT).fill(ELEMENT)` syntax. Just pass how many rows and cols you want to `myFunction` and it will create the table for you.

```js
myFunction(rows, cols) {

  return (
    <table>
      {Array(rows)
        .fill(null)
        .map((row) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              {Array(cols)
                .fill(null)
                .map((col) => {
                  return <td>Your Cell</td>;
                })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
    </table>
  );
}

// use it like this myFunction(10, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your function like this. We are mapping the two array and 1 is responsible for row and 2 is responsible for column.

```
const createTableRow = () => {
  return [...Array(SMTN1).keys()].map(itemOfSMTN1 => {
    return <tr>
      {
        [...Array(SMTN2).keys()].map(itemOfSMTN2 => {
          return <td></td>
        })
      }
    </tr>
  })
}
```

Comment: In the code, `SMTN1` looks like an integer, so you can't really map over it.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your data is a nested array something like below. The simplest way then is to map each item to a row, and each item in the row to a cell:

```
const data = [
  [1. 2. 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]

function myFunction(data) {
  return data.map((row) => (
    <tr>
      {row.map((val) => (
        <td>{val}</td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your code much then

```
class myComponent extends Component {

myFunction() {
//I would like to loop through two iterables, and make as many rows and columns
    let r = [];
    for (let i= 0; i <= SMTH1; i++) {
//add a <tr> opening tag
      const row = []
      for (let j= 0; j <= SMTH2; j++) {
        // add a <td> opening and </td> closing
          row.push(<td>content</td>);
        }
//add a </td> closing tag
      r.push(<tr>{row}</tr>);
    }

      return r;
}

render() {
    return <div>
      <table>
        {this.myFunction()}
        </table>
    </div>;
  }
}
```